# Python wont open a file named PRN.anything

Tags: python

I am trying to open a file named PRN.txt, using

```
open('PRN.txt', 'w')
```

It always fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PRN.txt'
```

I can call the file _PRN, PRO etc, it it will open fine. But PRN with any extension, any case and to any path does not work!

Python version 3.6.2

This is ridiculous. Please help!

Comment: No chance. That error's not going to be raised unless you're trying to open a non-existent file to read. This error is a no-repro.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'call the file'? Do you mean `open('_PRN.txt', 'w')` and `open('PRO.txt', 'w')` both work when the files are saved in the same directory as PRN.txt?

Comment: [Because this](https://superuser.com/questions/613313/why-cant-we-make-con-prn-null-folder-in-windows)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Its absurd.

Comment: Thank you kindall. So its true, you cant.

Comment: This error is reproducible on windows systems.